# Updating an excel worksheet from another sheet, depending on a value

Tags: vba, excel, logic

I am trying to create an If Statement that lets me send an number and a value to another workbook deepening on a value in a 3rd cell (weather the cell is is True or False"). The code that I want to run if the statement is True is below. I have tested this code, and it works, I just want it to happen if the third cell in the row is True. It then needs to carry the information from the number and value rows where the value is true into the function below.

```
        Dim itemName As String
        Dim itemPrice As String
        Dim myData As Workbook

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
        InvoiceNumber = Range("A2")
        qty = Range("B2")
        updated = Range("C2")


        Set myData = Workbooks.Open("HD:Users:user:Desktop:Inventory.xlsm")
        Worksheets("Orders").Select
        Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15").Select
        RowCount = Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        With Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = InvoiceNumber
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = qty
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = updated

        End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it could use another loop to go through a series of rows but I suppose that it may be a case where only a single operation is required.

```
Dim itemName As String
Dim itemPrice As String
Dim myData As Workbook
Dim sInvoiceNumber As String, dQty As Double, bUpdated As Boolean, iRowCount As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sInvoiceNumber = .Range("A2").Value
    dQty = .Range("B2").Value
    bUpdated = CBool(.Range("C2").Value)

    If bUpdated Then
        Set myData = Workbooks.Open("HD:Users:user:Desktop:Inventory.xlsm")
        With myData.Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15")
            iRowCount = .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
            .Offset(iRowCount, 0) = sInvoiceNumber
            .Offset(iRowCount, 1) = dQty
            .Offset(iRowCount, 2) = bUpdated
        End With
        myData.Close True '<-save and close the workbook
        .Range("C2") = Not bUpdated  '<- reset the updated field
    End If

End With
```

Rather than loop through the rows, a bulk transfer operation can be used by filtering the data.

```
Dim itemName As String
Dim itemPrice As String
Dim myData As Workbook
Dim iRowCount As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="TRUE"
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 3)
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                Set myData = Workbooks.Open("HD:Users:user:Desktop:Inventory.xlsm")
                .Cells.Copy Destination:=myData.Sheets("Orders").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                myData.Close True '<-save and close the workbook
                .Columns(3).Cells = False
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilter Field:=3
    End With
    If .AutoFilterMode Then AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

That filters on a worksheet cell value of TRUE in column C.

Comment: Works Great! Now... How do I get it to run though the "bUpdated" column and check that for True values, then carry out the function?

Comment: @tbowden - You are not going to want to keep opening and closing the workbook so a bulk operation is more appropriate. Does row 1 have column header labels and the data starts in row 2?

Comment: Yes it does ... Column 1: Invoice Number, Column 2: QTY, Column 3: Updated. Data starts in column 2.

Comment: @tbowden - see addendum above.

Comment: I've now moved the macro to a bigger work sheet that starts at row 6 and has many columns, how do I get it to start at that row? And I only need to send a few of the columns information, how do I do this without sending it all?

Comment: @tbowden - Typically, when a question changes sufficiently that it renders the accepted answer invalid, it should be a new question. Not trying to avoid an answer; it's just hard to hit a moving target. There are a number of ways to retrofit that answer to a larger data set but sample data should be provided so that the correct modifications can be generated.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on if statements.  I'm guessing you'd be able to figure it out from here:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

Basically, just use updated as the test condition in your if statement.

```
Dim itemName As String
Dim itemPrice As String
Dim myData As Workbook

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
InvoiceNumber = Range("A2")
qty = Range("B2")
updated = Range("C2")

If updated Then
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("HD:Users:user:Desktop:Inventory.xlsm")
    Worksheets("Orders").Select
    Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    With Worksheets("Orders").Range("a15")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = InvoiceNumber
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = qty
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = updated

    End With
End If
```